# how to total fields in single row in pig script?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a dataset containing student name and various subject marks comma delimited, how can I sum up marks of each student
Example dataset record

```
Student1 Marks1 Marks2 Marks3 Marks4
(Steve, 78, 23, 45, 34)
(Jobs, 23, 45, 12, 67)
```

Script

```
Student_New = FOREACH Student_File generate Student_Name, (int)TotalMarks:SUM($1,$2,$3,$4,$5); 
Dump Student_New;
```

I want to show output as (summing up all subject marks)

```
(Steve, 180)
(Jobs, 147)
```

Comment: Show your tried code.

Comment: Student_New = FOREACH Student_File generate Student_Name, (int)TotalMarks:SUM($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
Dump Student_New;

Comment: update/edit your question with the code, don't just chuck it into a comment

Answer (score 0):

SUM works on column data.Use '+' to add those columns.Note that this will work if you have loaded the Marks1 to Marks4 into int fields.

```
Student_New = FOREACH Student_File generate Student_Name, ($1+$2+$3+$4) as Total_Marks; 
Dump Student_New;
```